# Stuck on a rendering issue with a pyviz network

Tags: matplotlib, visualization, networkx, graphing, network-analysis

Im trying to create an interactive network analyis graph. im having trouble rendering an interactive version that tells me the connections each node has. I want to be able to click on a node and have the connections highlighted.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
```

## Add edges

```
for col in df_unique.columns:
    for row in df_unique[col]:
        for word1 in row.split():
            if word1.isalpha():
                for word2 in row.split():
                    if word2.isalpha() and word1 != word2:
                        G.add_edge(word1, word2)
```

## removes non-letter characters

```
for node in list(G.nodes()):
    if not node.isalpha():
        G.remove_node(node)
```

## color map for nodes

```
node_color_map = []
for node in G.nodes():
    if len(list(G.neighbors(node))) >= 10:
        node_color_map.append("#F5AC27")
    elif len(list(G.neighbors(node))) >= 5:
        node_color_map.append("#F2888B")
    elif len(list(G.neighbors(node))) ==1:
        node_color_map.append("silver")
    else:
        node_color_map.append("#90EE90")
```

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
```

## Objects for the Legend

```
gold_patch = mpatches.Patch(color="#F5AC27", label='10 or more connections')
pink_patch = mpatches.Patch(color="#F2888B", label = '5-9 connections')
green_patch = mpatches.Patch(color="#90EE90", label = '2-4 connections')
silver_patch = mpatches.Patch(color="silver", label = 'Only 1 connection')
```

#### Static Network Creation

```
plt.figure(figsize=(24,24))
plt.title('Network Analysis of Words in Chinese Restaurant Names')
plt.legend(handles=[gold_patch, pink_patch, green_patch, silver_patch])
# draw the graph
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, k=0.7, iterations=28)

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold',
        pos=nx.spring_layout(G, k=0.4, iterations=20),
        node_color =node_color_map,
        node_size=[G.degree(node)*100 for node in G],
        font_size=10,
        font_color='black',
        font_family='sans-serif',
        alpha=0.73)
```

```
from pyvis.network import Network
```

```
# create network
net = Network(height="750px", width="100%", bgcolor="#222222", font_color="white")

# add nodes
for idx, node in enumerate(G.nodes()):
    net.add_node(node, color=node_color_map[idx])

# add edges
for edge in G.edges():
    source, target = edge[0], edge[1]
    net.add_edge(source, target)
```

```
net.show("network.html")
```

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'render'


I tried rendering the Network in the Notebook. The code runs but i dont see any visualization.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Notebook, Update the following lines

```
net = Network(height="750px", width="100%", bgcolor="#222222", font_color="white", notebook=True, cdn_resources='in_line')

#save the HTML instead of show the html
net.save_graph("network.html")

from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(filename="network.html")
```